# Why doesn't my regular expression match my string?

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to match `D11-RONPLAYER_DEF_15_PO` using this regular expression:

```
"D\[0-9]+-\[A-Z]*PLAYER_(DEF\[0-9]*)_(\[^_]+)_"
```

but it does not match. How can I make it work?

Comment: Not too sure, but it seems a `_` is missing after DEF in the regex, and there seems to be extra `_` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with your sample input:

```
regexp {D\d+-[A-Z]*PLAYER_(DEF_\d*)_([^_]+)} $str match sub1 sub2
```

Printing the match groups yields:

```
% puts "$sub1\n$sub2"
DEF_15
PO
```